# Adding RCT3 to Steam

Tags: steam, rollercoaster-tycoon-3

I just found out that Roller Coaster Tycoon 3: Platinum was added to Steam. I bought the game years ago, and unfortunately lost the disk. Is there any way to add RCT3 to Steam w/o the disk?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Roller Coaster Tycoon 3 cannot be added to steam through the activation key.  It must be purchased through Steam to activate it.

For a list of all the games that can be activated on steam, see here:

https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=7480-WUSF-3601#which

If you want to put the game on your Game library as a Non Steam Game, then follow these steps:

```
Launch Steam.
Click the Games menu, choose Add a Non-Steam Game to My Library.
Browse for games on your computer or put a check next to the game(s) you wish to add to the Library.
Click Add Selected Programs
```

https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=2219-YDJV-5557

Comment: :( Alright, thanks anyways. I'll keep looking around, the disk has to be somewhere.